# Flutter : Slider custom Tooltip

Tags: flutter, dart, slider, tooltip, shadow

I want to make the custom tooltip with a background shadow for Slider in my app. Here is my code for the current slider.

```
SliderTheme(
          data: SliderThemeData(
            activeTrackColor: AppColor.royalGreen,
            inactiveTrackColor: AppColor.black12,
            thumbColor: AppColor.royalGreen,
            thumbShape: CircleSliderThumbShape(),
            showValueIndicator: ShowValueIndicator.always,
            valueIndicatorColor: AppColor.white,
            valueIndicatorTextStyle: TextStyles.sliderTooltipText,
            // overlayShape: SliderComponentShape.noOverlay,
            // overlayColor: AppColor.behan24
          ),
          child: Slider(
            value: _currentSliderValue,
            onChanged: (double value) {
              setState(() {
                _currentSliderValue = value;
              });
            },
            label: "${_currentSliderValue.toString().split('.')[0] + 'L'}",
            min: 5,
            max: 50,
          ),
        ),
```

This is what I want to achieve.

[image]

What I have achieved so far.

[image]

Any help will be appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using the library [flutter_xlider](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_xlider)

With this, you can customize using the Tooltip and add a shadow to create the effect of elevation.

```
      FlutterSlider(
        values: [300],
        max: 500,
        min: 0,
        onDragging: (handlerIndex, lowerValue, upperValue) {
          _lowerValue = lowerValue;
          _upperValue = upperValue;
          setState(() {});
        },
        tooltip: FlutterSliderTooltip(
            textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, color: Colors.black),
            boxStyle: FlutterSliderTooltipBox(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                color: Colors.white,
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                    spreadRadius: 5,
                    blurRadius: 7,
                    offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )),
      ),
```

This is what you will achieve:

[image: Elevated ToolTip]